# Why I can't bypass function()'s inside hover()?

Tags: jquery, hover

This is my code:

```
$(".link").hover(
    function () {
        FunctionA($(this));
    },
    function () {
        FunctionB();
    }
);
```

why I can't just write:

```
$(".link").hover(
    FunctionA($(this)),
    FunctionB()
);
```

will fast the code...

Comment: when you use it like that the function are invoked first then the values returned by those function are passed as arguments to `hover()`, in this case you can pass `FunctionB` as it is not expecting any arguments... so `$(".link").hover(function () {
    FunctionA($(this));
}, FunctionB);` should be fine

Comment: Try `$( ".link" ).hover( FunctionA, FunctionB );`

Comment: @ostapische `FunctionA` is expecting a parameter

Comment: @ArunPJohny you can use `this` in `FunctionA`. Like `FunctionA(){ var el = $( this ); }` and `el` will be `$(".link")`.

Comment: @ostapische yes that requires a change in the `FunctionA` definition, you have to mention it in the solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think better use function without params, then you access `jQuery.Event` and get it's `target` element instead of `this`, or use `this` if you want. `function FunctionA( event ) { alert( this === event.target ); }` alert will be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".link").hover(
    FunctionA($(this)),
    FunctionB()
);
```

Passing $(this) is totally useless. Infact, if you call (and you can) hover in this way:

```
$(".link").hover(FunctionA, FunctionB);
```

In FunctionA you can access to the caller:

```
var FunctionA = function() {
    console.log($(this));
    /* will print $(".link") */ 
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u42Td/)** here.

Basically, as you can see in the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), hover expects two handler functions (handlerIn and handlerOut), both without parameters.

Comment: but `var FunctionA` it is not a Handler, its a variable linked to a function. and I need to use `function FunctionA() {}`

Comment: @markzzz they are identical if you use it in `window` context. When you use `var something =` in other `function` variable (function ot whatever you want) accessible only in that `function`.